# Same resource in different services of AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I have a doubt about why a resource is not occupied in some moments of the simulation. I have 2 services [service A and service B] that seize 2 resources each of them (one in common [resource C] and one different [resource A - service A; resource B - service B]. Both services have a task priority defined by the same function. Normally, the priority of the agents in the queue of service A is greater than the ones in service B, but resource A has a higher utilization than resource B. Sometimes there are agents in the queue of both blocks, resource A is not available and resources B and C are available, but service B is not seized. Why does this happen?

I have completed several times the simulation and I always have the same problem.

Comment: are the resources a,b and c coming from different resourcepools or are you using custom resource choice... you need to add more info

Comment: also include details on the priority function and how you call for resources in your services

Comment: Also, try to simplify your test use case until you find the real root cause of the unexpected behavior. Helps yourself and us to help you :)